# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'h5py.utils'

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, huggingface-transformers

So I am trying to run a chat-bot which I built using Tkinter and transformers as a standalone exe file [I am using Windows 10] but I would get a run time error every-time I execute it. Is there something I am doing wrong? I have been trying different commands for nearly 2 days.

Error generated below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.modeling_tf_utils because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
No module named 'h5py.utils'

Traceback (most recent call last): RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.models.auto because of the following error (look up to see its traceback): Failed to import transformers.modeling_tf_utils because of the following error (look up to see its traceback): No module named 'h5py.utils'
```

I have tried using the follow commands and added and removed additional hidden-imports but that didn't work:

```
pyinstaller -w  --icon=logo.ico --hidden-import="pkg_resources.py2_warn" --hidden-import="h5py.defs" --hidden-import="googleapiclient" --hidden-import="apiclient" --hidden-import=tensorflow --hidden-import=pytorch --hidden-import=transformers --hidden-import=tqdm --collect-data tensorflow --collect-data torch --copy-metadata tensorflow --copy-metadata torch --copy-metadata h5py --copy-metadata tqdm --copy-metadata regex --copy-metadata sacremoses --copy-metadata requests --copy-metadata packaging --copy-metadata filelock --copy-metadata numpy --copy-metadata tokenizers --copy-metadata importlib_metadata --hidden-import=“sklearn.utils._cython_blas” --hidden-import=“sklearn.neighbors.typedefs” --hidden-import=“sklearn.neighbors.quad_tree” --hidden-import=“sklearn.tree” --hidden-import=“sklearn.tree._utils” chatbot.py
```

Comment: ```pip install h5py``` will probably do it

Comment: @TheodorPeifer I tried this already, that did not help the problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. Here's what I did

Before I start, do not use -onefile flag in your command.

1. I ran the command `" pyinstaller -w  --icon=logo.ico --hidden-import="h5py.defs" --hidden-import="h5py.utils" --hidden-import="h5py.h5ac" --hidden-import="h5py._proxy" --hidden-import=tensorflow  --hidden-import=transformers --hidden-import=tqdm --collect-data tensorflow --collect-data torch --copy-metadata tensorflow --copy-metadata torch --copy-metadata h5py --copy-metadata tqdm --copy-metadata regex --copy-metadata sacremoses --copy-metadata requests --copy-metadata packaging --copy-metadata filelock --copy-metadata numpy --copy-metadata tokenizers --copy-metadata importlib_metadata chatbot.py "`
2. Go to the `\Lib\site-packages\certifi` folder and copy the cacert.prem file.
3. When you try to run the exe file from the generated dist folder, you will get an OSError about a missing TLS CA certificate bundle because it's pointing to a certifi folder that does not exist within the dist folder. **From the generated dist folder, go to the main folder, Create a new folder and rename it "certifi" and paste the cacert.prem file in it.**
4. Re-run your exe file and it should work, it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a SPEC file to build your executable with Pyinstaller, the hiddenimport= part must be updated.

Here is a snippet of my SPEC file pointing to the h5py modules.

```
     datas=[],
     hiddenimports=[
       'h5py.defs',
       'h5py.utils',
       'h5py.h5ac',
       'h5py._proxy',
     ],
     hookspath=[],
```